# Can I print a variable from one function in another .py file

Tags: python

for example lets say I have a file called "utils.py".
I have a function that passes user input through a series of "if" statements. Every time X conditions are met the original variable is altered and saved as a new variable then passed down to the next if statement.
I want to access the final altered variable from a source file called "main.py". I would prefer if there was a method with no temp file. I have searched for an answer online for a while but found nothing quite as specific as what i am looking for.

to clarify i have a file called "utils"

```
if x == "y":
    s = x.replace("blah", "blah")
    print s
global I1_b
I1_b = s
```

then in another file called "main" i would like to call I1_b

```
if this == "that":
    print(I1_b)
```

Comment: If you do `import utils` then you can use `utils.I1_b`

Comment: But it's generally better to have the function return the value, rather than using global variables like this.

Comment: what do you mean have the function return the value?

Comment: The code you posted from `utils.py` is presumably in a function, since `global` has no effect outside functions. So it should do `return s`. Then `main.py` can do `I1_b = func()`

Comment: so i could remove the global and do something like "I1_b = func(s)" in the main.py?

Comment: Yes, that's usually the best way

Answer (score 0):

You can import the utils.py file in the main.py file, then use I1_b there.

It would like this:

```
# In main.py
import utils
if this == "that":
    print(utils.I1_b)
```

Comment: i have this in my existing code however it keeps throwing errors saying I1_b is not recognised,

Comment: It says it's not defined, right? You have to "change" its value first, you can assign a value to utils.I1_b in main.py and it would print, but I think that's not what you want. So you should make a method in utils that returns utils.I1_b value and do:
print(utils.method())

or you can change utils.I1_b value (in this same utils.method) and just print it in main.py.

Comment: my apologies the error 'function object has no attribute I1_b'

Comment: That happens because the code in utils.py hasn't been ran, you need to put it all inside a method and call it before printing utils.I1_b.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in the utile.py folder would be better inside a function and import that function in the main.py file. The code in utils.py will now always be executed once you import anything from it.

```
from utils import function_x

print(function_x())
```

Answer (score 0):

`global` is not the correct tool here. That is used inside a module (file) to define a global scope (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword), and read/edit variables accordingly.

The best solution is to import the `I1_b` variable from the `utils` module, like: `from utils import I1_b`, and use it as you intended

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_value(x):
    if x == "y":
        s = x.replace("blah", "nah")
        print(f"X is {x}")
        return s

your_answer = get_value(input("Input y: "))
print(your_answer)
```

To access it from another file, see @barmar comment `import utils`